# $\sin(x^2)>\sin(x)^2$ , for $0<x<\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$, using infinite series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$\sin(x^2)>\sin(x)^2$ ,for $0<x<\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$,using infinite series

any hints.

Comparing the terms for

$\sin(x)^2\simeq x^2-\frac{x^4}3+\frac{2 x^6}{45}
-\frac{x^8}{315}+\frac{2 x^{10}}{14175}
-\frac{2 x^{12}}{467775}+\frac{4 x^{14}}{42567525}-\frac{x^{16}}{638512875}+O(x^{18})$
\

$\sin(x^2)\simeq x^2-\frac{x^6}6+\frac{x^{10}}{120}
-\frac{x^{14}}{5040}+\frac{x^{18}}{362880}
-\frac{x^{22}}{39916800}+\frac{x^{26}}{6227020800}\\
-\frac{x^{30}}{1307674368000}+O(x^{33})$

doesn't work because $\frac{x^{10}}{120}>\frac{2 x^6}{45}$ but $-\frac{x^6}6<-\frac{x^4}3$

Comment: Doesn't give you much? It gives you a lot...

Comment: @TKM you are missing a bracket around the 10 in the second series.

Comment: I don't see what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

case 1: $1\le x\le\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$, then
$$1\le x\le x^2$$
so
$$\sin^2{x}<\sin{x}\le sin{x^2}$$
case 2: $0<x<1$, then
$$0<x^2<x<1<\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$$,

since $$f(x)=\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}$$Monotone decreasing in $[0,\dfrac{\pi}{2}]$, then we have
$$\dfrac{\sin{x}}{x}<\dfrac{\sin{x^2}}{x^2}\Longrightarrow x^2\sin{x}<x\sin{x^2}$$
so when $x\neq 0$,then we have $$x\sin{x}<\sin{x^2}$$
so
$$\sin^2{x}<x\sin{x}<\sin{x^2}$$
case 3:$x=0$,then 
$$\sin^2{x}=\sin{x^2}$$
By Done

Comment: Very good solution indeed. +1